# Test if file exists with Postgres

Tags: c, postgresql

I need to create a function to test if a file exist with postgres. I'm doing it with C language, but i'm having a problem. The code is:

```
#include "postgres.h"
#include <string.h>
#include "fmgr.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include<sys/stat.h>

#ifdef PG_MODULE_MAGIC
PG_MODULE_MAGIC;
#endif

/* by value */

PG_FUNCTION_INFO_V1(file_exists);
Datum
file_exists (PG_FUNCTION_ARGS)
{
   text *fileName= PG_GETARG_TEXT_P(0);

   struct stat buf;
   int i = stat(fileName, &buf);
     /* File found */
     if ( i == 0 )
     {
       PG_RETURN_INT32(1);
     }
     PG_RETURN_INT32(0);

}
```

I think the problem is with the first argument in the "stat" function, because fileName is a text and this function receives a char.

This is the first time i write C code, so maybe everything is wrong.

Comment: How is `text` defined? Can't you use `char*` instead of `text*` ?

Comment: i think it's defined in postgresql.h and should be something like this: typedef struct {
    int4 length;
    char data[1];
} text;

Comment: Seems obvious: just reference `fileName->data` instead of `fileName`.

Comment: @netcoder: Except that `data` is not nul-terminated so handing `fileName->data` to `stat` is just a shortcut to a memory access error.

Comment: @muistooshort: That's also obvious, to me anyway. :)

Comment: Are you aware of the built-in `pg_stat_file()` function?

Comment: @willglynn: That's useful, except (quoting the manual [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-GENFILE)): `Only files within the database cluster directory and the log_directory can be accessed.` Quick & dirty trick: You can circumvent this security barrier by adding a symlink to your postgres data dir pointing to a directory of interest ..

Comment: @willglynn: that functions worked fine for me, thanks

Answer (score 5):

If you dig through the headers you'll find this in `server/c.h`:

```
/* ----------------
 *      Variable-length datatypes all share the 'struct varlena' header.
 *...
 */
struct varlena
{
    char        vl_len_[4];     /* Do not touch this field directly! */
    char        vl_dat[1];
};

#define VARHDRSZ        ((int32) sizeof(int32))

/*
 * These widely-used datatypes are just a varlena header and the data bytes.
 * There is no terminating null or anything like that --- the data length is
 * always VARSIZE(ptr) - VARHDRSZ.
 */
typedef struct varlena bytea;
typedef struct varlena text;
```

so there's your definition of the `text` data type. Note this rather important part of the comment:

> There is no terminating null or anything like that

That indicates that you absolutely do not want to treat `fileName->data` as a C string unless you like segfaults. You need a way to convert a `text` to a nul-terminated C string that you can hand to `stat`; there is a function for that: `text_to_cstring`.

The only documentation for `text_to_cstring` that I can find is [this comment in the source](http://doxygen.postgresql.org/varlena_8c_source.html#l00121):

```
/*
 * text_to_cstring
 *
 * Create a palloc'd, null-terminated C string from a text value.
 *
 * We support being passed a compressed or toasted text value.
 * This is a bit bogus since such values shouldn't really be referred to as
 * "text *", but it seems useful for robustness.  If we didn't handle that
 * case here, we'd need another routine that did, anyway.
 */
```

There is also [an example that uses it](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/spi-examples.html):

```
char *command;
/*...*/

/* Convert given text object to a C string */
command = text_to_cstring(sql);

/*...*/
pfree(command);
```

You should be able to do something like this:

```
struct stat buf;
char *fileName = text_to_cstring(PG_GETARG_TEXT_P(0)); 
int i = stat(fileName, &buf);
pfree(fileName);
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. text_to_cstring did not work for me, then I realized that the problem is that i did not include the header file for text_to_cstring func. How silly is that. so i had to search in the /usr/include/postgresql/your_version/server/utils/ folder till i found it finally and then all worked well. Try

```
char *filename = text_to_cstring(PG_GETARG_TEXT_PP(0));
```

but dont forget to include first builtins.h

```
#include "utils/builtins.h"
```